# Crossbrowser: Css rule not parsed in Explorer 8 (div#main>div)

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My JQuery app is working properly in all the browser except Explorer 8..

And what is not make my app working is that is not parsed this css rule:

```
  div#main>div {
       display:none
   }
```

Someone can tell me please how can i write this differently to be accepted in Explorer 8?

If needed this the structure that need to be styled:

```
 <div id="main">
     <div id="1">
     ...
     </div>
     <div id="2">
     ...
     </div>
     <div id="3">
     ...
     </div>
 </div>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: this should totally work. your css must get overwritten somewhere else. maybe use spaces like "#main > div {"

Comment: You can remove the div before #main. It is useless in your declaration and adds complexity.
Try #main>div

Comment: use #main div { display:none; }

Comment: Possible duplicat [css child (>) selector not working in IE8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306853/css-child-selector-not-working-in-ie8)

Comment: Ah thank you Vucko. 
By the way i see that they come to a similar solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alex said there was nothing wrong with the rule itself.
But believe me was not parsed.

I had to to include that rule in a separate file:

```
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

Is a file with just that rule.
But now everything works fine.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. If you do need it, then there's something else going on which is wrong. It might be better to fix the actual problem than introduce a hack to work around it.

Comment: You are right. Did not find yet what was causing the issue.
So far that it works as a temporary solution to parse that rule in explorer 8